# how to correctly analyse the costs produced by an EXPLAIN statement

Tags: postgresql

In order to analyse my query I trailed it with the following statement

```
EXPLAIN (FORMAT json, COSTS true)
```

which produced the output here below. The point is: is there a **total** cost I can compare with other queries? Or do I have to sum up all the `total costs` for each node?

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Sort",
      "Startup Cost": 48.47,
      "Total Cost": 48.97,
      "Plan Rows": 200,
      "Plan Width": 16,
      "Sort Key": ["r.range_start"],
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Plain",
          "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "CTE times",
          "Startup Cost": 1.17,
          "Total Cost": 1.25,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 8,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Relation Name": "hst_energy_d",
              "Alias": "hst_energy_d",
              "Startup Cost": 0.00,
              "Total Cost": 1.15,
              "Plan Rows": 10,
              "Plan Width": 8,
              "Filter": "((idinstrum = 4) AND (id_device = 122))"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
          "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "CTE ranges",
          "CTE Name": "times",
          "Alias": "times",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 5.02,
          "Plan Rows": 1000,
          "Plan Width": 16
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
          "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "CTE rounded_hst",
          "Relation Name": "hst_energy_d",
          "Alias": "hst_energy_d",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 1.47,
          "Plan Rows": 10,
          "Plan Width": 576,
          "Filter": "((idinstrum = 4) AND (id_device = 122))"
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Hashed",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Startup Cost": 29.57,
          "Total Cost": 33.08,
          "Plan Rows": 200,
          "Plan Width": 16,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Hash Join",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Join Type": "Left",
              "Startup Cost": 0.33,
              "Total Cost": 24.57,
              "Plan Rows": 1000,
              "Plan Width": 16,
              "Hash Cond": "(r.range_start = hd.round_time)",
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "CTE Name": "ranges",
                  "Alias": "r",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                  "Total Cost": 20.00,
                  "Plan Rows": 1000,
                  "Plan Width": 8
                },
                {
                  "Node Type": "Hash",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.20,
                  "Total Cost": 0.20,
                  "Plan Rows": 10,
                  "Plan Width": 16,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "CTE Name": "rounded_hst",
                      "Alias": "hd",
                      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                      "Total Cost": 0.20,
                      "Plan Rows": 10,
                      "Plan Width": 16
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: `"Total Cost": 48.97,` The total cost is accumulated in the top-node.

Comment: the `"Total Cost": 48.97,` is a sum of all already - no?..

Comment: I wasn't sure guys. If you say so I'm ok with that!